# Linking library (from assembly files) with main.c in Makefile

Tags: linux, assembly, makefile

Im passionate about assembly and wanted to start coding from home on linux instead of mac I usually use.

I really struggle for 4 days about this issue.

you can find my makefile and clone repository at the following url:

```
<code>NAME =                libfts.a
ASM_FILES =         ft_isascii  \

OS := $(shell uname)
ifeq ($(OS), Darwin)
ASM_COMPILER =      ~/.brew/bin/nasm -f macho64 -g
else
ASM_COMPILER =      nasm -f elf64 -g
endif
ASM_SRC_DIR =       srcs/
ASM_OBJ_DIR_NAME =  obj
ASM_OBJ_DIR =       $(ASM_OBJ_DIR_NAME)/
ASM_OBJ :=          $(addsuffix .o,$(ASM_FILES))
ASM_OBJ :=          $(addprefix $(ASM_OBJ_DIR),$(ASM_OBJ))
TEST =              maintest.out
TEST_FILES =        maintest
C_COMPILER =        clang -Wall -Werror -Wextra -O3
TEST_DIR_NAME =     test
TEST_DIR =          $(TEST_DIR_NAME)/
TEST_OBJ :=         $(addsuffix .o,$(TEST_FILES))
TEST_OBJ :=         $(addprefix $(TEST_DIR),$(TEST_OBJ))
OBJ_PATHS :=        $(ASM_OBJ) $(TEST_OBJ)
all: $(NAME)
$(NAME): $(ASM_OBJ)
    ar rc $(NAME) $(ASM_OBJ)
test: re $(TEST_OBJ)
    $(C_COMPILER) -L. $(NAME) $(TEST_OBJ) -o $(TEST)
$(ASM_OBJ): $(ASM_OBJ_DIR)%.o: $(ASM_SRC_DIR)%.s
    @/bin/mkdir -p $(ASM_OBJ_DIR)
    $(ASM_COMPILER) $< -o $@
$(TEST_OBJ): $(TEST_DIR)%.o: $(TEST_DIR)%.c
    $(C_COMPILER) -c -I. $< -o $@
clean:
    -/bin/rm -f $(OBJ_PATHS)
    /usr/bin/find . -name "$(ASM_OBJ_DIR_NAME)" -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -delete
fclean: clean
    -/bin/rm -f $(NAME)
    -/bin/rm -f $(TEST)
re: fclean all
.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

I have this error message when I try "make test" on the linux:

```
    test/maintest.o: In function `main':
    test/maintest.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `ft_isascii'
    undefined reference to etc.
```

.h content:

```
#ifndef _LIBFTS
# define _LIBFTS

#include <stddef.h>

int         ft_isascii(int c);

#endif
```

ft_isascii.s content:

```
global _ft_isascii

section .text

_ft_isascii:                ; int ft_isascii
    and     edi, 0xffffff80 ; mask with the 128 firsts bits left to 0 as ASCII range from 0 to 7f in hexa (just below 80)
    sete    al              ; SETE sets AL to 1 if above condition code means "equal", otherwise it sets AL to 0.
    movzx   eax, al
    ret
```

I would REALLY be thanksful for any tips to solve this issue...

Regards,

Comment: Please put the relevant code into the question.  Questions on Stack Overflow must be self contained, it is not sufficient to just link to some code.  Also, try to explain what your problem is.  You said that you “struggle for 4 days about this issue” but then fail to explain what the issue is.  I downvoted your question until you fix these issues.

Comment: Your problem could be that macOS has an underscore decorating all C functions which isn't present on ELF targets but unless you explain what issue you face, it's hard to tell if that's your problem.

Comment: Before you can fix makefile, make sure you can build the project from command line writing all build steps manually. Makefile is just script file storing such single steps (and being a really powerful tool to make such storage nicely categorized, turning common build steps into general rules, etc... from my experience makefiles may feel limited at start, but in the long run it's much better than modern build systems like gradle, which need actual code to finish some build steps, instead of simple (ok, not always that simple with make) rule. Once you can build from CLI, look for difference...

Comment: I mean, it may be your problem is not with makefile at all, but the actual source. make is extension over project, not mandatory thing, you can build everything without make, if you are stubborn enough to write everything manually for each target file. (BTW, I didn't click on your link, so I have zero idea, what is your *actual* issue)

Comment: ok please remove the downvotes I edited according to the rules ;)

Comment: fuz I tried to add remove the underscore without any success. @Ped7g my issue is specifically with this line :
clang -Wall -Werror -Wextra -O3 -L. libfts.a test/maintest.o -o maintest.out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems to be fixed:

First, on ELF targets (most Unixes except macOS), C functions are not decorated with an underscore.  To fix your code, remove the leading underscore from all symbols.  Make sure to remove it everywhere.

Second, the linker when looking at an archive (`.a` file) only picks files it needs right now to satisfy dependencies.  So when you pass the archive before `maintest.o`, the linker doesn't take anything from the archive at all as it doesn't need any `ft_...` symbols at that point.  These symbols are only needed once the linker has seen `maintest.o`.  To fix this issue, move the `$(NAME)` operand to after `$(TEST_OBJ)`.  As a general rule of thumb, always place libraries after object files on the linker command line.

On macOS, you won't observe this problem because they use lld, the LLVM linker, which is a bit unconventional in that it defers the choice which objects to take out of archives until it has looked at the symbol tables of all operands, making your actually broken invocation work.  Don't depend on this behaviour, please.

Comment: Thank you Sir, the first and second suggestion was what I really needed ;)